# How can I place the nginx.conf file directly in the website root folder?

Tags: nginx, web-server

I experienced a WordPress plugin do this, and I was not aware it was possible.
The plugin informed me it did some changes in the **nginx.conf**, but I couldn't understand how it could it that since it does not have permission to do this in the **/etc/nginx** folder.

I checked and saw it had created an **nginx.conf** file directly in the www root folder of the website.

Does nginx include the file automatically when placed in the root folder of the website?

Answer (score 3):

It **can** do that, but only if it's badly configured. I sincerely hope it's not, because that would make it easy for whoever found a hole in any of your wordpress plugins, wordpress itself, or any other code, to re-configure your webserver. This is most likely something you do not want.